# How to loop child divs parent by parent with respect to the horizontal level in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">child1</div>
        <div class="child">child2</div>
        <div class="child">child3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">child4</div>
        <div class="child">child5</div>
        <div class="child">child6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">child7</div>
        <div class="child">child8</div>
        <div class="child">child9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">child10</div>
        <div class="child">child11</div>
        <div class="child">child12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">child13</div>
        <div class="child">child14</div>
        <div class="child">child15</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">child16</div>
        <div class="child">child17</div>
        <div class="child">child18</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have sortable divs and i want to save the order of divs. But if i use jquery each function it loops parent divs and passing another parent after taking all childs of it vertically.What i am trying to do is getting child1,child4,child7,child10.. and so on. If we think this as a table i want to take values of cell row by row but jquery each doing this column by column.
The output that i want is 1,4,7,10,13,16,2,5,8,11,14,17,3,6,9,12,15,18

[here is code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xgzaofs6/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xgzaofs6/6/)

```
var arr=[];
var count = $(".parent")[0].children.length;
for (var i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
$(".parent").each(function(){
arr.push($(this.children[i]).text())
});
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code made for you and let me know, If it's working for you or not.

```
var cnt = 0;

$(".parent:first-child .child").each(function () { cnt++; });

for (var i = 1; i <= cnt; i++) {

    $(".parent").each(function () {

        console.log($(this).children('.child:nth-child(' + i + ')').html());
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response and work. Your code works well but i should check the Joey's answer.He wrote before.Thank you again.